# How can i transfer the data from here to here

Tags: reactjs

I want to transfer the props that i got in a one component to another component.

```
function StarWar(props) {

    function handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(props.other)
        return <div><Battle value={props.other}/></div>
    }

    if (props.value == 0) {
        return <div>
            <button className="btn btn-warning starwar"
                onClick={handleClick}>
                Start war
            </button>
        </div>
    }
    return <h1>Choose {props.value} more avangers</h1>
}
```

from here i want to pass the values to Battle which am trying it in handleClick(e)
Here is also my Battle class

```
export class Battle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Battle begins here</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

It sees correctly to my but the values dont bind

Comment: You are returning html element from handleClick. Why????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Use JSX and ternary operator concept to display Battle component.`, This is the working solution of your question.

```js
  function StarWar(props) {

        function handleClick(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(props.other)
            return <div><Battle value={props.other}/></div>
        }

        if (props.other == 0) {
            return <div>
                <button className="btn btn-warning starwar"
                    onClick={handleClick}>
                    Start war
                </button>
            </div>
        }
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
          {props.other !== null ? (
            <div>
              <Battle value={props.other} />
            </div>
          ) : null}
          <h1>Choose {props.value} more avangers</h1>
        </React.Fragment>    
        )
    }
  
class Battle extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value
  };
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.value !== nextProps.value) {
      this.setState({ value: nextProps.value });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
        <h1>Battle begins here</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    ReactDOM.render(<StarWar other="20"/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: It dont works well it didnt pass the values to battle again

Comment: @boris i have updated the code with componentWillReceiveProps() in Battle component, Now it will update for new props.